# Recover Pendrive

Tags: data-recovery, usb-flash-drive, previous-versions

I accidentally made my pendrive (Sandisk) bootable with windows 11 on which I had kept important backup files. Is there any solution to recover data on that pendrive. I think (but not sure) previously pendrive was formatted with NTFS and now it is formated with FAT32.

Comment: No, there's no solution for that.

Comment: Made bootable *how exactly*?

Comment: A commercial data recovery service *might* be able to recover *some* data, at considerable expense. If you plan on that, **stop using the drive**.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen I used windows media creation tool

Comment: It's like @harrymc says then. Only if you have say a 32 GB flash drive you may be able to recover 'raw' files (by signature); so for example file0001.jph, file0002.mp3, file0004.mp4 etc. .. You can use something like PhotoRec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows Media Creation Tool not only formats the disk, but it then
writes to it a very sizeable amount of data.

This would surely not only destroy the file-table that indicates where
your files are, but will also very likely overwrite your data.

Sorry to say, but it seems like your data is lost.

Comment: Is there any possible way to recover some of the files?

Comment: Perhaps if the data was not overwritten. But as the Windows installation is measured in gigabytes, this would mean that your data should not have been placed in the first few gigabytes on the disk but following them. I don't know how much data you had and of what kind.

Comment: I think the backup was 5gb to 6bg

Comment: The Windows 11 ISO is said to be 5.37 GB or more. Do you think that there were files that *started* after this amount?

Comment: I am not sure about it, the usage of the pendrive was very less. but co-incidentally I used pendrive on that day, and it was connected ideally. Also I needed to created bootable pendrive. I didn't double checked which pendrive was inserted.

Comment: I used DMDE and Recuva recovery software but most files shown are that which I think I never kept on my pendrive. Few files are revocered but those are not important as other files

Comment: [MiniTool](https://www.minitool.com/) is another excellent tool. But understand that the chances are low.